# @react-navigation/elements HeaderBackButton not visible on Android

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am using `@react-navigation/elements` (1.3.17 - latest as of writing this). However the `HeaderBackButton` component is not visible on Android, but the default header from my stack navigator does show the back button on Android.

```js
<Header
  headerLeft={({tintColor}) => (
    <HeaderBackButton
      canGoBack={true}
      tintColor={tintColor}
      onPress={navigation.goBack}
    />
  )}
  title={props.title}
  headerRight={headerRightProps =>
    props.headerRight && (
      <View style={{paddingRight: 15, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        {props.headerRight(headerRightProps)}
      </View>
    )
  }
/>
```

On iOS this works fine, but on Android results in:

[image: HeaderBackButton not visible]

There are also some other problems, such as `headerShadowVisible` not working on `Header`. There is never a shadow visible (as seen in the picture), neither on iOS and Android. Perhaps they are related. Does anyone have any experience with this?